# Elegant localized Java ORM with default locale

Tags: java, jpa, localization, default, criteria

We have a DTO for UI purposes; a Java POJO like this: `id` (primary key to keep track), `code` (non-localized attribute),
and, most notably, `name` and `description`. These two attributes need to be localized.

We need an Entity and a database model that allow for localization of that "tuple" (`name`, `description`).
We use JPA with an Oracle database, but normally try to avoid vendor-specific features. In Java, we prefer Criteria API queries.
If non-standard ways have their strong benefits, we will always consider them, though.

**I. – No restrictions regarding the database design**

1. What is the most straight-forward, or (if differing) the best performing, database model and mapped Java Entity for this?
2. What is the SQL to select *one* Row (`id`, `code`, `name`, `description`) for a given `id` and *locale* - returning values for `name` and `description`
   taken from a *default* localization if the requested locale is not the default and that translation does not yet exist for this object (`id`)?
   And what is the Criteria API *Java code* for this, i.e., to directly populate our DTO in a given locale context? The use case is a german user who is listing
   data sets where not all localized data is available in german, so in some rows we need to display english text.

We would prefer to have the *fall-back* decisions being made on the database side. If the code becomes cleaner or more
maintainable, or the query clearer or faster, we would probably accept that the default-localized data is *always*
transferred to Java (even if it is not strictly needed in every case), plus data for the *one requested* localization (if needed and / or available). However we would really try to avoid
to fetch the data for *all* locales, since most query results will go "directly" to the UI without any caching, presented to a logged-in user who
favors to view all data in their personal locale.

**II. – Special database design**

Now let's assume an *additional requirement*, regarding the database design. A simple table is required for the
*base* data, along with the default-localized *text* data - i.e., merely the above DTO mapped to *one simple database table* with columns `id`, `code`, `name` and `description`.
If data is requested for the default locale - english - it would then be sufficient to do a simple select from this table.

All localized data (`name`, `description`) for non-default locales - e.g., german - should be kept somewhere else (one or more additional tables). Data for non-localized
attributes, such as the above `code` property, should be stored according to DRY, i.e., not be duplicated.

I tend to call something like this a "one to one-or-more" mapping - what is the common name for such a design? Can the fact that adding localized data (columns) must be done in *more than one table* somehow be enforced?

And again, what are the database and Java models and queries (SQL, and JPA / Criteria API) like in section **I.**?